# curl response empty while browser works ok

Tags: curl

The Chrome browser can open the url `https://api.my-ip.io/v1/ip` which will returns client ip. However, when I do it with `curl -iv https://api.my-ip.io/v1/ip`, it gives empty response.

```
~/ppp/validator $ curl -iv https://api.my-ip.io/v1/ip
*   Trying 23.88.33.229:443...
* Connected to api.my-ip.io (23.88.33.229) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=myip01.eucentral.hetzner.internal.workshell.uk
*  start date: Oct 17 17:46:42 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 15 17:46:41 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.my-ip.io" matched cert's "api.my-ip.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /v1/ip HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.my-ip.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.87.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: On my end it returns the IP perfectly fine. The site might have a firewall, or you don't have curl setup properly.